# Getting Result of IO Monad in ghci

Tags: haskell, io

Given:

```
Prelude> let x = return 100 :: IO Int
```

Trying to evaluate `x` returns its wrapped value.

```
Prelude> x
100
```

But, I can't get its value via `show`.

```
Prelude> show x

<interactive>:4:1:
    No instance for (Show (IO Int)) arising from a use of ‘show’
    In the expression: show x
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = show x
```

What's going on when I type `x` in ghci?

Comment: `x >>= print` will print it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you enter an expression of type `IO t` into GHCi, it unwraps it and prints the resulting value. That is if you enter `ioExp`, GHCi executes `val <- ioExp; print val` (whereas if you enter a non-IO expression `exp`, GHCi executes `print exp`).

Answer (score 4):

You can't `show` an `IO Int` action. The action may require to perform side effects to produce the `Int`, such as asking the user for such number. Instead, the type of `show` promises to return a `String`, i.e. a plain, pure string without any side effect.

You can define your own effectful variant of `show`, if you want:

```
showIO :: Show a => IO a -> IO String
showIO = fmap show
```

Note how the result above is not a plain string, but is wrapped inside the `IO` monad, as it should be.